# Wordpress php echo inside echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

Wordpress, echo inside echo

> Error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or
> identifier or variable or number

```
<?php 
  echo do_shortcode("[simple-weather location='$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_CITY'], $_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT']' days='6' night='no' units='metric' text_align='center' display='block' style='large-icons' api='1f2420650944ec72e4acd03a7ed18514']"); 
?>
```

I would be grateful for your help in debugging the code!

Comment: Too many single-quotes. Use concatenation.

Comment: Required reading: [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: `"[simple-weather location='".$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_CITY'].", ".$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT']."'` ..etc

Comment: @ADyson
Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enclose the PHP variables in curly brackets. As currently written, `PHP` thinks that the variable is only `$_SERVER` and not the `$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_CITY']`. When complex variables like array items or object properties are used in quotation marks, always add curly brackets around them to help PHP distinguish what is a variable and what is plain text.

Here is a working code:

```
<?PHP 
  echo do_shortcode("[simple-weather location='{$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_CITY']}, {$_SERVER['IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT']}' days='6' night='no' units='metric' text_align='center' display='block' style='large-icons' api='1f2420650944ec72e4acd03a7ed18514']"); 
?>
```